# PDO and binding multiple value sets during insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Using PDO in PHP, when having to insert multiple rows into a table at once, I've used sql that looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO some_names (firstName, lastName) VALUES ('Joe', 'Smith'),('Fred','Sampson'),('Lisa','Pearce');
```

As you can see I'm inserting three rows with one statement. The reason I do this is that I believe it is more efficient than executing three distinct statements to insert the rows.

So my question is this: how do I do this in PHP if I want to be able to bind my values to a statement like I do in single statement:

```
$query= ("INSERT INTO table (firstName, lastName) VALUE (:firstName, :lastName)", array = (
    "firstname"=>$firstName,
    "lastName"=>$lastName));
```

So my question is: Is there any way to bind in a multi-insert statement? Something like:

```
INSERT INTO table (firstName, lastName) VALUES((:firstName, :lastName),(:firstName, :lastName));
```

Comment: Just bind with `?` and pass all your data.

Comment: " I believe it is more efficient" - nope, it is not

Comment: Could you please come up with a better suited title?

Comment: @YourCommonSense so, making multiple requests to the data base is the same then making one?

Comment: It's not the same, but as I have explained in my answer there's barely any difference in performance. Any overhead stemming from the multiple calls is completely negligible.

Comment: @YourCommonSense hmm, got it, thanks!

Comment: @Dharman so the commonly expressed mantra about the 'fewer round trips the better' is incorrect ?

Comment: @Strawberry It depends on what you have in mind. This mantra is a good general guide, but in the above case there would be negligible performance improvement and it would make the code unnecessarily complex. What you are saying applies mostly to the N+1 problem or situations when making extra calls could be easily avoided at no cost to code readability. There is an overhead of multiple calls, but the question you should be asking is when is it sensible to avoid that overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create your query text wtih `?` placeholders as:

```
INSERT INTO table (firstName, lastName) VALUES (?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?)
```

And execute it. Sample code can be:

```
$data = ['Joe', 'Smith','Fred','Sampson','Lisa','Pearce'];
$placeholders = ['(?, ?)', '(?, ?)', '(?, ?)'];  // but you should define this data according to your data
$query = 'INSERT INTO table (firstName, lastName) VALUES ' . implode(',', $placeholders);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($data);
```

Answer (score 4):

In theory, it might sound like a single statement is more efficient because you avoid making multiple calls to MySQL server, but the reality is that this a micro-optimization and you are overcomplicating your code for barely any benefit.

The cool thing about prepared statements is that it is prepared once and can be executed multiple times. This already saves you parsing the SQL statement multiple times. Simply prepare a statement outside of a loop and then execute it inside a loop.

```
$names = [['Joe', 'Smith'], ['Fred', 'Sampson'], ['Lisa', 'Pearce']];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO table (firstName, lastName) VALUES(?,?)');
foreach ($names as $name) {
    $stmt->execute($name);
}
```

If you wrap the whole thing in a transaction as Your Common Sense suggested in the comments then there is no noticeable difference in performance compared to one big statement.

```
$names = [['Joe', 'Smith'], ['Fred', 'Sampson'], ['Lisa', 'Pearce']];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO people (firstName, lastName) VALUES(?,?)');
$pdo->beginTransaction();
foreach ($names as $name) {
    $stmt->execute($name);
}
$pdo->commit();
```

Comment: I would suggest wrapping multiple inserts in a transaction, to overcome a possible delay from [innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12611/is-it-safe-to-use-innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit-2) and for the better integrity in general